# A Matrix Optimization Problem

Tags: matrices, algorithms, optimization, computational-complexity

Given an $n\times d$ matrix $Y$,
I am looking for an algorithm to find an $n$-vector $\mathbf{v}$ ($0\le \mathbf{v}_i\le 1$ for all $i$) that minimizes $\sum_{i:X_i<0}X_i$, where $X:= \mathbf{v} Y$. Is there such an algorithm with running time polynomial in $n$?

If it helps, we also know that if $\forall i, \mathbf{v}_i \in \{0,1\}$ then $\sum_{i:X_i<0}X_i \ge -\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: You want to minimize the sum of the negative entries of $\mathbf{X}$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Rahul in this case since the terms in the sum are all negative, the question is equivalent to *maximizing* the sum of the magnitudes of the negative entries. Does that lead to a linear programming problem as well?

Comment: Where does that $-\sqrt{n}$ lower bound come from? For some matrix $Y$, I can get values for the sum that are smaller than that bound. Are there additional constraints on $Y$ you didn't mention?

Comment: Yes, the matrix $Y$ has a very long story - it is obtained via an iterative process on a graph. Unfortunately, I do not know how I can give a more detailed specification of $Y$ without having to describe the whole iteration and the model behind it. I just hoped there may be a general solution before complicating the question with too many details.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem as stated here is non-convex and there is no polynomial time solution for it, unless $P=NP$ (to the best of my knowledge about this problem), but you can approximated it with a convex optimization program as I explain in the following:

Your non-convex program can be formulated in the following form:

Let $v\in R^n$ and let $e_i$ be the $i$th standard basis vector (i.e. the $i$th element of $e_i$ is $1$ and the rest are $0$).

you have:

$\text{minimize}_{v} \sum_i \min(0,e_i^T Y^T v)$

subject to: $0\preceq v\preceq 1$

and the function $\min(0,e_i^T Y^T v)$ is the component that makes it non-convex.

Here is a suggestion, write a convex relaxation of the problem as:

$\text{minimize}_{v,t} \sum_i t_i$

subject to:

$0\preceq v\preceq 1$

$t_i\leq 0$

$ t_i\leq e_i^T Y^T v$

The problem with this convex representation is that you have a feasible solution for $t_i \rightarrow \infty$, so here is where the approximation can help, you want $t_i$ be as close to $e_i^T Y^T v$ as possible, so solve the following program instead:

$\text{minimize}_{v,t} \sum_i t_i + (t_i-e_i^T Y^T v)^2$

subject to:

$0\preceq v\preceq 1$

$t_i\leq 0$

$ t_i\leq e_i^T Y^T v$

This program is convex, and can be solved "efficiently" using any quadratic solver, and approximates what you're looking for. I hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't this representation going to excessively penalize solutions where $e_i^TY^Tv>0$?

Comment: @Rahul You are right, but this is the best approximation you can do. There are two solutions for that, one is adding a regularization weight $C$ for $(t_i-e_i^T Y^T v)^2$, and using the objective $\sum_i t_t+C(t_i-e_i^T Y^T v)^2$, and the second solution is applicable when you know alot about $Y$ and the distribution of $~~t_i-e_i^T Y^T v~~$, then you can use a better norm to penalize the distance. (e.g. $L_1$ may be a better choice if you know that the distibution is Laplacian)

Comment: Well, I'm just concerned that the solution this approach finds could be far from the true global minimum -- but whether that's a problem depends on what the OP wants to use the solution for. Anyway, can you explain how you know that there is no polynomial time solution? You're not saying that any nonconvex problem is automatically NP-hard, are you?

Comment: That's why you can change the weight of the penalty term by tuning $C$ (maybe on some held-out data). There are exceptional non-convex problems that can be solved efficiently, to the best of my knowledge this is not one of them. But if you have a better solution for this problem, I'll be happy to know about it.

Comment: @Rahul, By the way thanks for your comment, I probably need to be more careful about the hardness issue, initially I thought you can reduce a MaxSat problem to this one, but I don't have a full reduction mechanism now. So I'll edit that part of my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you said something like "I'm fairly sure there is no polynomial time solution for it", I would completely agree. That was all I was asking. I thought maybe you had a proof. (If you do find one that would be a great thing to add to the answer!)